# Flask-Python. How do you use external module in Flask and passing data to html?

Tags: python, flask

I'm building desktop app UI and I'm trying to move everything into Flask so I can just present everything in `html/css/boostrap`.

But the code below doesn't work.

How do you get `found.productId` and the rest of loops to display on `ali.html`?

**app.py**

```
from aliexpress_api_client import AliExpress

@app.route('/ali')
def ali():
    aliexpress = AliExpress('1234', 'bazaarmaya')

    data = aliexpress.get_product_list(['productId', 'productTitle', 'salePrice', 'originalPrice', 'imageUrl'],
                                       keywords="shoes", pageSize='40')
    for product in data['products']:
        productId = product['productId']
        productTitle = product['productTitle']
        salePrice = product['salePrice']
        originalPrice = product['originalPrice']
        imageUrl = product['imageUrl']
        founds = print(productId, productTitle, salePrice, originalPrice, imageUrl)

    if founds == founds:
        return render_template('ali.html', founds=founds)

    return render_template('ali.html')
```

**ali.html**

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}
 <table>
     <tr>
         {% for found in founds %}
         <td>{{found.productId}}</td>
         <td>{{found.productTitle}}</td>
         <td>{{found.salePrice}}</td>
         <td>{{found.originalPrice}}</td>
         <td>{{found.imageUrl}}</td>
         {% endfor %}
     </tr>
 </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Why are you using `print` in `founds = print(productId, productTitle, salePrice, originalPrice, imageUrl)`? `print()` returns `None`. Maybe `founds = [productId, productTitle, salePrice, originalPrice, imageUrl]` instead?

Comment: I made the changes but it doesn't render anything

Comment: Try getting rid of `if founds == founds:` and just `return` once. I don't know enough about the external API you're using to know why you need to have a default route out of the function.

Comment: What is output of the print? Does it print anything?

Comment: removed if founds == founds: and did 1 return, still no output.

Comment: I think I've got it. `{{found.productId}}`tries to access `found` as though it's a dict, but it's not. Now you're sending a nested list to the template. `{% for found in founds %}` is correct. Then change `<td>{{found.productId}}</td>` to just `<td>{{found}}</td>`. Do you see an output (I know it will be a complete mess, but just seeing an output _at all_ will confirm my suspicions)?

Comment: it works! @roganjosh

Comment: one question though why it only return 1 results and not 40 ?

Comment: @JackAQ I'm writing an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that `print()` will *return* `None`. So:

```
founds = print(productId, productTitle, salePrice, originalPrice, imageUrl)
```

is just equivalent to `founds = None`. Basically useless.

So, the first thing to do is to give `founds` a structure. Your options are basically a `dict` and a `list`. A list is simplest to work with in your example (but not necessarily your actual code):

**app.py**

```
from aliexpress_api_client import AliExpress

@app.route('/ali')
def ali():
    aliexpress = AliExpress('1234', 'bazaarmaya')

    data = aliexpress.get_product_list(['productId', 'productTitle', 'salePrice', 'originalPrice', 'imageUrl'],
                                       keywords="shoes", pageSize='40')
    for product in data['products']:
        productId = product['productId']
        productTitle = product['productTitle']
        salePrice = product['salePrice']
        originalPrice = product['originalPrice']
        imageUrl = product['imageUrl']
        founds = [productId, productTitle, salePrice, originalPrice, imageUrl]

    return render_template('ali.html', founds=founds)
```

*Note*: there's a problem either way here. The `for` loop is going to overwrite data on each loop, so maybe you want a dictionary but you'll need to give it unique keys. Or you define a list beforehand and apppend to it in the loop. *This example will only give you the last item from the loop and it's up to you to deal with it accordingly*.

Then:

**ali.html**

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}
 <table>
     <tr>
         {% for found in founds %}
         <td>{{found}}</td>
         <td>{{found}}</td>
         <td>{{found}}</td>
         <td>{{found}}</td>
         <td>{{foundl}}</td>
         {% endfor %}
     </tr>
 </table>
{% endblock %}
```

You can use the `.` notation if you pass a dictionary to the template and want to access things by key. But there are other problems to address first so this answer runs the risk of spiraling into too much depth. `jinja2` syntax (in your templates) is remarkably like regular python.